# BeautifulSoup не может найти элемент на странице

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, bs4

Код парсера:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:85.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.1', 
    'accept':'*/*'
    }
URL = f'https://discord.com/gifts/aaabbbccc'


def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r


def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    articles = soup.find_all(
        'div', class_='colorHeaderSecondary-3Sp3Ft size16-1P40sf')

    print(articles)


def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    get_content(html.text)


parse()
```

Вывод:

```
[]
```

Описание проблемы:
BeautifulSoup не может найти элемент на странице, хотя он есть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: вам стоит предоставить `URL` и `HEADERS`, или пример `soup`-а после работы программы, иначе ваш пример невозможно воспроизвести, вследствие определить проблемное место

Comment: Добавил значения в переменные.

Comment: то, что вы видите такой див в инспекторе еще не значит, что он, с таким же названием класса есть в soup